# Returning the value from a higher order function

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like this:

```kotlin
import okhttp3.Authenticator
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.Response
import okhttp3.Route

class TokenExpirationImplementation(
    private val tokenExpirationHandler: TokenExpirationHandler
): Authenticator  {

    override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
        var token : String? = null
        tokenExpirationHandler.provideToken { providedToken ->
            token = providedToken
        }
        return response.request.newBuilder()
            .removeHeader(AUTH_HEADER)
            .addHeader(AUTH_HEADER, token)
            .build()
    }
}
```

What I'm expecting to happen is when the `authenticate` method is called I should get the token from the provideToken callback. What actually happens, it will return null.

I know I can just do the async call directly in the authenticate method, but I'm curious if there's any way in which I could turn the callback into a return.

For a little bit more context, I'm trying to implement OkHTTP's `Authenticator` interface but use a higher order function instead of a direct API call.

Edited for a better context

Comment: So basically you want to wait until your callback is called before returning from `authenticate`?

Comment: @user3738870 exactly!

Comment: Only possible with coroutines. Otherwise, you must in turn specify a callback parameter in this function instead of a return value. Explanations here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o

Comment: Could you provide the codes for your network call? is it a coroutine?

Comment: edited my initial question with the exact code, hopefully this makes more sense now.

@devmike01 I'm not calling the authenticate method myself; it's getting called by okhttp when my initial network call returns a 401.

Answer (score 1):

There's an async call in your `provideToken` and thus its operation is not going to be instant, but the `authenticate()` will return immediately after you have called it. There's a high probability that `provideToken` would still be waiting for the network call to return by the time you call the `authenticate()` function hence the `null` result.

If your network call is a suspend function, you can make `provideToken` a suspend function and retrieve the value using a coroutine API.